# Layout parallel columns in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, org-mode

I'm seeking to layout paragraphs as follows:
1. In the introduction, I'd have the paragraphs across all columns.
2. Then follow two columns with opposing opinions in parallel. It differs than a two-columns layout that the two columns will be parallel and that the content on the left will always remain on the left, the right always on the right across multiple pages. Even if the amount of argument of the left column is shorter, the argument of the right column should not float into the left column.

Here is an example in HTML:
https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Corinthians+15&version=CCB;KJ21
Used to compare different translations.

Below is my attempt to achieve the effect.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Here are the normal paragraph crossing colmuns.

\blindtext

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \section{Argument on the Left}
  Because I am on the left, so must I be not right?

\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \section{Argument on the Right}
  Because I am on the right, so I must be right!

  \blindtext
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

It almost achieved the effect, except that there is no gap between the two columns.

Here is a screenshot of the result:
[image]

What would be a better solution?

How could I achieve the same in org-mode with export to PDF (via LaTex)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have separated columns, it is sufficient to use smaller minipages and to add a space between them. Minipages are boxes, and you can either use a fixed space (with ~~~ or \hspace{}), but the better is rubber space \hfill.

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Here are the normal paragraph crossing colmuns.

\blindtext

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
  \section{Argument on the Left}
  Because I am on the left, so must I be not right?
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
  \section{Argument on the Right}
  Because I am on the right, so I must be right!

  \blindtext
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\noindent` avoids the normal paragraph spacing and `\hfill` "pushes minipage towrads left and right margin.

But it is not the best solution. You will have problems to manage properly page breaks and there is a specific package to does exactly what you want.

The package `paracol` defines a parallel environment with 2 (or more) columns and provides a way to "synchronize" them by switching between cols. It takes care of page breaks and is definitely what you want.

Here is an example with paracol

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{paracol}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Here are the normal paragraph crossing colmuns.

\blindtext

\begin{paracol}{2}
  \section{Argument on the\\ Left}
  Because I am on the left, so must I be not right?

  \switchcolumn
  \section{Argument on the\\ Right}
  Because I am on the right, so I must be right!

  \blindtext
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, section numbering is coherent between columns, but there are many ways to customize the package if you prefer not. Look at the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/paracol/paracol-man.pdf) 
Also note that I had to add a manual line break to have section titles properly formatted, but it is a minor drawback.

Concerning, org-mode, I use it, but I have no experience with export and cannot really help you. But with the flexibility of paracol, you can find some way to define macros that do what you need. Maybe if you provide a org-mode export, people can try to find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the nearly perfect solution!